# Create a object from a nested json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following json that i receiving from my server in angular, I would like to create an customize object from this Json

```
{
    "showsHall": [
        {
            "movies": [
                "5b428ceb9d5b8e4228d14225",
                "5b428d229d5b8e4228d14226",
            ],
            "shows": [
                "5b428d6b9d5b8e4228d14229",
                "5b428ef69d5b8e4228d1422a",
            ],
            "_id": "5b428d439d5b8e4228d14228",
            "hallName": "Small hall",
            "rows": 10,
            "seats": 40,
        }
    ],
    "movie": [
        {
            "showsHalls": [
                "5b428d439d5b8e4228d14228",
                "5b43490592bd380e30fef376"
            ],
            "shows": [
                "5b428d6b9d5b8e4228d14229",
                "5b466d9d75a55841c48bacfc"
            ],
            "_id": "5b428ceb9d5b8e4228d14225",
            "movieName": "Moonwalker - Michael jackson",
            "directorName": "Jerry Kramer, Colin Chilvers",
            "movieDescription": "Anthology movie by, and starring, Michael 
             Jackson in his prime, combining a number of...",
        }
    ],
    "takenSeats": [],
    "_id": "5b428d6b9d5b8e4228d14229",
    "showDate": "7/10/2018",
    "showStartTime": "4:00 PM",
    "showEndTime": "6:00 PM",
}
```

The wanted result that i would like to get, should be:

```
{       
        "hallName": "Small hall",
        "movieName": "Moonwalker - Michael jackson" 
        "takenSeats": [],
        "_id": "5b428d6b9d5b8e4228d14229",
        "showDate": "7/10/2018",
        "showStartTime": "4:00 PM",
        "showEndTime": "6:00 PM",
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing some code?

Comment: Yes, I am looping throw it in the html template with *ngFor
But i want to create the object inside the TS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original object is named `source`, you can assemble your new object as follows:

```
 const newObject = {       
    "hallName": source.showsHall[0].hallName,
    "movieName": source.movie[0].movieName,
    "takenSeats": source.takenSeats,
    "_id": source._id,
    "showDate": source.showDate,
    "showStartTime": source.showStartTime,
    "showEndTime": source.showEndTime
}

// have a look at it
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Here you go. This should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I cant  understand why people down-voted my question.

Comment: You're welcome. -- Mostly one gets downvotes if there is no code to show what you've tried on your own. I agree with this opinion up to a certain limit of complexity. But in your case I actually upvoted your post because from my point of view it was no harm at all to give you this little hint and help you to getting used to the handling of JSON-objects. Good luck with your project.